# How correct call make in bash script?

Tags: bash

I am just started learning bash scripts and I try to write simple script for create a project by cmake from source and then make it. Here is a text of script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mkdir -p cmake
cd ./cmake
exec cmake ../
exec make
```

But after creating a project by cmake, script do nothing. Without script project builds successfully. May be anyone know what the problem?

Comment: `cd ./cmake` should be `cd cmake`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`exec`](http://ss64.com/bash/exec.html) is "Instead of the rest of the script, execute this command". Remove them both:

```
# ...as before...
cmake ../
make
```